# Google Cloud Shell Keep Disconnecting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, vps, google-cloud-shell, gcloud-compute

looking for solution to prevent google cloud shell disconnecting when it found you idle, even it also disconnect when you run some processing and leave system idle.

message shown `Connection to Cloud Shell has been lost. Any additional changes will not be saved.`

Comment: As @MaratB mentioned it is working as intended and it is impossible to change the inactive time. However I would like to suggest you to try installing SDK and check if you are still facing the same problem. 
You can follow this link to install [SDK](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/google-cloud-cli-and-sdk-setup) if you are planning to install.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is by design, as Cloud Shell is intended for [interactive use only](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits).

Comment: @asks - workarounds can result in losing access to Cloud Shell for your account.

Comment: That's exactly right.  Trying to subvert Cloud Shell limitations or violate Terms of Service in any other way is a sure way to get your account banned.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is running a ping command within a TMUX Terminal.

```
apt install tmux
apt update
tmux
ping google.com
Ctrl+b "
```

The downside of this is you'll be working halfscreen.